# CSS :export blocks

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've just had my mind blown a little bit...

I've been looking into alternative ways to share variables between CSS/JS for the sake of having a single source of reference.

In *half-following* one or two tutorials, I've ended up with an `:export {}` block declaration in a CSS file being referenced in a React Component:

[image: Screenshot of source]

This example shows the CSS `:export` declaration, the import reference in my Component and the rendered DOM of my test app.

Validation services tell me this is not valid CSS (as well as the helpful comments below), even though the syntax resembles a pseudo-selector.

I found this solution in [this book](https://frontend-cookbook.ack.ee/pages/implementation/SharingVariables.html). Why I'm both confused and excited is that this solution is compiling, but I'm not leveraging Webpack's [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) or [PostCSS-Modules](https://github.com/outpunk/postcss-modules) as dependencies.

Is anyone able to provide an explanation as to why `:export` in CSS or SCSS is behaving like `module.exports`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This does not seem to be valid CSS to my knowledge. Have a look at how we used to do it years ago (sharing values between CSS and JS) https://github.com/dominikwilkowski/breakpointjs

Comment: Wow. Small world. Design System Meetup is the best. Poorly framed question in haste/excitement. Will amend.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid CSS to me. (Syntactically, maybe, but there is no `:export` selector and no `namespace` property - that's what the disabled stylelint would complain about.) You will have to look into the documentation of your module loader/bundler/transpiler (webpack?) for how this works. The dark magic is in the build system. Can you show us what you are using?

Comment: Also that `.#{$namespace}-avatar` syntax looks like [sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation), not plain css.

Comment: Have provided more context and reframed the question.

Comment: Looks like it's a css-modules thing: https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-icss-composes and https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules-scope

Comment: From glancing over this it looks like this is how css-modules compiles it's css and shares data.

Comment: "*I'm confused as this solution is compiling, but I'm not leveraging Webpack's css-loader or PostCSS-Modules*" - then what *are* you using? Please show us your webpack config, or even make a [mcve]